# PHP Include always point to same location no matter where page is located

Tags: php, html

So, my page consists of multiple includes, such as a `head.php` file, `footer.php` and so on.

I included them using this code:

```
<?php include '/includes/head.php' ?>
```

The thing is, it only works for files above the 'includes' directory, as the starting slash doesn't go to the root of the site in PHP.

How would I go about including all the files, no matter where the current .php file is located?

Comment: You need the absolute path. What does `realpath(dirname(__FILE__))` give you?

Comment: How would I use that?

PHP newbie

Comment: If you want includes to work regardless of the current location of the script, you need to use the absolute path. For example, `/var/www/html/includes/head.php`, but that's just a lame guess, echo out what Darren says.

Comment: @user3779981 Look what `Dave Chen` just commented. We need you to do this: `echo realpath(dirname(__FILE__));` and show us the result.

Comment: /includes/head.php is the path from the root folder. It works fine using the starting slash in HTML, but doesn't do the same in HTML. I did fine a little code: 
    <?php 
       $head = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
       $head .= "/includes/head.php";
    ?>
That seemed to work, but I'd rather do it more efficiently

Comment: Oh, and using that code shows my root folder as would be expected:
C:\Users\Tom\OFFICIAL_WEBSERVERwamp\www\basic-training\public

Comment: I think I'll replace all my includes with the new code I commented above

Comment: Oh also, you need to replace the backslash with `/`, because the backslash is an escape character. You can also replace it with two backslashes. `C:/Users/Tom/OFFICIAL_WEBSERVERwamp/www/basic-training/public/`

Comment: I'm not trying to point like that though. Thing is, this is currently using a server on my computer, when teh site goes live, it'll be on a web server, where everything already works. It's just I need it to work both on my server, and on my host

Comment: @DaveChen Remember: Windows = `BACKSLASH(\)` and Linux = `FORWARDSLASH (/)`, just how the directories work, so to be honest, the OP should just the `realpath()` option and have that variable stored somewhere. Usually done in the index for many MVC applications.

Comment: @Darren Yep, I pointed out that if he wanted to copy and paste it into his code, he would need to escape the escape characters. At the OP: You'll want to save a variable that holds where your /includes directory is, so when you release the code on your server, you only need to change one line to make it work on both machines.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using [`realpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php).

In most MVC apps, they have something like this:

```
DEFINE('ROOT_DIR', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/');
```

set in their `index.php`. Since all traffic goes through the `index.php` file, the define will be there.

Allowing you to do something like this:

```
include(ROOT_DIR. 'includes/head.php');
```

It saves you a **lot** of trouble and rewriting.

There are other options where you can store it in a config, which practically does the same thing.

---

[**`As stated in the comments by Dave Chan`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877460/php-include-always-point-to-same-location-no-matter-where-page-is-located/24877776?noredirect=1#comment38640434_24877776)

> You may also use [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) if you want ROOT_DIR to be accessible for every .PHP enabled page

Comment: Perfect example. You may also use [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) if you want ROOT_DIR to be accessible for every .PHP enabled page.

Answer (score 0):

To tap into the parent directory try adding ../ in the beginning of your string such as:

include '../includes/head.php';